# Add business days without Saturday sunday and specific holidays in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I want to add days to a date in R, except Saturdays and Sundays and specific holidays. Suppose I have a dateset :

```
d <- dmy("25-7-2016","26-7-2016")
days <- c(3:4) 
data <- data.frame(d,days)
data
```

I want to add #days (days column) to a date (d column) I have tried the following code:

```
library(bizdays)
library(lubridate)
cal <- Calendar(weekdays=c('sunday', 'saturday'))
data$f <- offset(d, days, cal)
data
```

I can get the days without considering Saturdays and Sundays. But I want to exclude a specific holiday i.e. 27-7-2016. I tried to incorporate this specific holiday but getting an error. The code which I tried is as follows:

```
holiday <- dmy("27-7-2016")
cal <- Calendar(holiday,weekdays=c('sunday', 'saturday'))
data$f <- offset(d, days, cal)
data
```

Could you please help me to get is solved. Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

Works if you add a `start.date` and `end.date`:

```
holiday <- dmy("27-7-2016")
cal <- Calendar(holidays = holiday,
                start.date = dmy("01-07-2016"),
                end.date = dmy("01-09-2016"), 
                weekdays=c('sunday', 'saturday'))
data$f <- offset(d, days, cal)
data
```

Gets you:

```
           d days          f
1 2016-07-25    3 2016-07-29
2 2016-07-26    4 2016-08-02
```

FYI, `Calendar` gives a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In Calendar(holidays = holiday, start.date = dmy("01-07-2016"),  :
This function will be deprecated, use create.calendar instead.
```