# add 1 business days to dates using timedate or lubridate

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I am trying to add a business day to some dates but cannot seem to get it right. What I have currently is:

```
 d$plusOneBusinessDay <- AllDays + 1
```

or

```
 d$plusOneBusinessDay <- AllDays + days(1) # adds one day but also adds weekend and holidays
 d$plusOneBusinessDay <- AllDays + wday(1) # addes one week
```

I am only interested in business days, so if something occurs on a Friday I want to roll it over to the monday. I have been looking at `lubridate` and `timedate` also `RQuantLib` but cannot get it working.

Any help would be great!

Data:

```
d <- data.frame(AllDays=seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"),
                             as.Date("2015-08-18"),"day"))
```

Comment: try with `bizdays`

Comment: Sweet thanks! This seems to work on my data: `create.calendar(name="mycal", weekdays=c('saturday', 'sunday'))` Then `... mutate(plusone_date = offset(orig_date, 1, "mycal"))… `

Comment: This post helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749336/adding-15-business-days-in-lubridate "Check 2018 Update"