# Want to increment a previous date row field by a value in another column and Lag Not working

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lag

I have a simple table (included below), where I want to create a third column, call it st_date, where the value on the first row will be a fixed value (say 01/30/2020).

For each subsequent row, I want the value in st_date to be the lagged Date value from the previous row + the value in lengths in terms of business days (not weekends)

Ex:
So on row #2, the value should be 01/30/2020 + 7 Working Day = 02/10/2020
On Row #2, the value should be 02/10/2020 + 10 = 02/25/2020

The code to generate the original table is

```
tmp <- as.data.frame(unclass(rle(t_1$BB_W_D))) %>% 
  mutate(st_date=df_start_date)
```

==> df_start_date is my starting date I want to have in row #1

```
structure(list(lengths = c(1L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L), values = structure(c(NA, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("Down", "Up"), class = "factor"), st_date = structure(c(18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 18291, 
18291, 18291, 18291, 18291), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-113L))
```

When I run the next code set,

```
tmp <- tmp %>% 
  mutate(st_date=lag(st_date,1)+lengths)
```

It creates the below, where it is not retaining the value in Row #1 and each subsequent row is now just incremented from the original value of 01/30/2020.

Not sure where the disconnect is here since I have used lag before and it never exhibited this behavior before

```
structure(list(lengths = c(1L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L), values = structure(c(NA, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("Down", "Up"), class = "factor"), st_date = structure(c(NA, 
18298, 18301, 18297, 18293, 18292, 18293, 18295, 18293, 18295, 
18300, 18298, 18296, 18294, 18296, 18299, 18296, 18301, 18301, 
18294, 18292, 18293, 18297, 18293, 18292, 18293, 18292, 18293, 
18292, 18294, 18292, 18295, 18294, 18304, 18301, 18296, 18292, 
18301, 18292, 18297, 18293, 18294, 18292, 18292, 18294, 18294, 
18293, 18293, 18293, 18293, 18293, 18299, 18303, 18293, 18292, 
18294, 18297, 18299, 18301, 18297, 18293, 18292, 18293, 18295, 
18293, 18295, 18300, 18298, 18296, 18294, 18296, 18299, 18296, 
18301, 18301, 18294, 18292, 18293, 18297, 18293, 18292, 18293, 
18292, 18293, 18292, 18294, 18292, 18295, 18294, 18304, 18301, 
18296, 18292, 18301, 18292, 18297, 18293, 18294, 18292, 18292, 
18294, 18294, 18293, 18293, 18293, 18293, 18293, 18299, 18303, 
18293, 18292, 18294, 18297), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-113L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that uses a simple `for` loop. This code

```r
library(bizdays)

create.calendar(name="my_cal", weekdays = c("saturday", "sunday"))

for (idx in 2:nrow(df)) {
  days.to.add   <- df$lengths[idx]
  
  previous.date <- df$st_date[idx - 1]
  
  new.date      <- offset(previous.date, days.to.add, "my_cal")
  
  df$st_date[idx] <- new.date
}

head(df)
```

gives you that output.

```r
  lengths values    st_date
1       1   <NA> 2020-01-30
2       7     Up 2020-02-10
3      10   Down 2020-02-24
4       6     Up 2020-03-03
5       2   Down 2020-03-05
6       1     Up 2020-03-06
```

Here is the result data frame.

```r
structure(list(lengths = c(1L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L), values = structure(c(NA, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("Down", "Up"), class = "factor"), st_date = structure(c(18291, 
18302, 18316, 18324, 18326, 18327, 18331, 18337, 18339, 18345, 
18358, 18367, 18374, 18379, 18386, 18396, 18403, 18417, 18431, 
18436, 18437, 18439, 18449, 18451, 18452, 18456, 18457, 18459, 
18460, 18465, 18466, 18472, 18477, 18494, 18508, 18515, 18516, 
18530, 18533, 18541, 18543, 18548, 18549, 18550, 18555, 18558, 
18562, 18564, 18568, 18570, 18572, 18584, 18600, 18604, 18605, 
18610, 18618, 18628, 18642, 18652, 18654, 18655, 18659, 18663, 
18667, 18673, 18684, 18695, 18702, 18705, 18712, 18724, 18731, 
18745, 18759, 18764, 18765, 18767, 18775, 18779, 18780, 18782, 
18785, 18787, 18788, 18793, 18794, 18800, 18803, 18822, 18836, 
18843, 18844, 18858, 18859, 18869, 18871, 18876, 18877, 18878, 
18883, 18886, 18890, 18892, 18894, 18898, 18900, 18912, 18928, 
18932, 18933, 18936, 18946), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-113L), class = "data.frame")
```

HTH

Comment: MACOS: Appreciate the straightforward solution.  Guess I gotta stop thinking that something is wrong with my code (ie what am I doing wrong with Lag) vs that the function sometimes does not fit what I need it to do.  Still annoys me that I cannot use lag to calculate values and have to resort to using for loops.

Comment: Lag does not work in your case because your calculation for row n depends on the calculated value of row n - 1. If you really want a solution without a ```for``` loop I can think about it. I'm sure it is not difficult.

Comment: Your input makes sense though does seem a little limiting.  The for loop works well for what I need it to do.  Now that I know that lag is not the be-all end-all, I can modify the for loop to have it do what I want with regards to this type of calculation.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with `purrr::accumulate`.

Like @Alexlok, I was inspired by [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749336/adding-15-business-days-in-lubridate) (thanks Rich!).

`accumulate` applies a function with two arguments (`.x` and `.y`) on the previous value and the next value in a vector. You can define an initial value with `.init =` .

So in the first case `.x = .init = "2020-01-29"` and `.y = temp$lengths[1] = 1`.

Next we create a sequence of dates from the start date to a long enough distance in the future that we couldn't possibly have too many holidays. Then we use the `timeDate::isBizday` function to determine which of those dates is a business day and subset it by the length into the future (`.y`).

We then return that date which becomes `.x` for the next round. That process completes for the entire `tmp$lengths`.

`accumulate` returns `.init` as the first value, so we can use `[-1]`. It also returns the same type as `.x`, so we need to convert back to a date with `as.Date`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(timeDate)
as_tibble(tmp) %>%
   mutate(st_date = as.Date(accumulate(lengths,~{
     dates <- .x + days(seq(1,3+2*.y))
     bizdates <- dates[isBizday(as.timeDate(dates))]
     bizdates[.y]},.init = as.Date("2020-01-30")-1)[-1]))
## A tibble: 113 x 3
#   lengths values st_date   
#     <int> <fct>  <date>    
# 1       1 NA     2020-01-30
# 2       7 Up     2020-02-10
# 3      10 Down   2020-02-24
# 4       6 Up     2020-03-03
# 5       2 Down   2020-03-05
```