# Add new column to dataframe in R that contains next business day from date in another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, that consists of two columns: name and date.
Now I would like to add a new column - date 2 - and the values within these new columns should be the next business day taken from the date in the same row.

Is there a way to add the new column and directly say that it needs to take the value from column 2 and search the next business day for column 3?

Comment: check out the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749336/adding-15-business-days-in-lubridate

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.